get a constant mounting point to share folders thru app
I have 3 hard drives in my PC, one for Ubuntu system and two others to keep files I need to use with different app. But for that I need to have persistent path location for those hard drives, and for now I'm lost in disk app. The location I get thru disk aren't readable by my app yet like they were under Fedora .
